# Can't use inversion on inductive predicate

Tags: coq, dependent-type

I'm stuck on a simple proof about an inductive predicate. I have to prove that the natural 0 is not positive, where a natural is a list of bits, and 0 is any list with only bits that are 0s.

```
H1: pos Empt
____________ (1/1)
Nat
```

[This](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Predicates.html) chapter of [Certified Programming with Dependents Types](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/) seems to suggest I use `inversion`, but I get an error message.

```
Require Import Coq.Program.Program.

Inductive Bit: Type :=
  | Zer: Bit
  | One: Bit.

Inductive List (type1: Type): Type :=
  | Empt: List type1
  | Fill: type1 -> List type1 -> List type1.

Implicit Arguments Empt [[type1]].

Implicit Arguments Fill [[type1]].

Definition Nat: Type := List Bit.

Inductive pos: Nat -> Prop :=
  | pos_1: forall nat1: Nat, pos (Fill One nat1)
  | pos_2: forall nat1: Nat, pos nat1 -> forall bit1: Bit, pos (Fill bit1 nat1).

Program Fixpoint pred (nat1: Nat) (H1: pos nat1): Nat :=
  match nat1 with
  | Empt => _
  | Fill Zer nat2 => Fill One (pred nat2 H1)
  | Fill One nat2 => Fill Zer nat2
  end.

Next Obligation.
inversion H1.
```

Comment: Strange. I can use inversion outside the obligation. `Theorem T1: pos Empt -> False. Proof. intro H1. inversion H1. Qed.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Theorem T1` is not equivalent to the `Obligation`. In the latter, you're supposed to build an element of `Nat`, which itself is a `Type` (btw, why aren't you using `Set` here? You do not seem to be manipulating higher-order types in this development).

As the error message says, you cannot perform a case analysis (`inversion` is built upon that) on an element of `Prop` for that (see in particular section 4.5.4 of the [Coq manual](http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.4/refman/)). However, in this case, you're not interested in building an actual `Nat`, you merely want to prove that this case is impossible. For that, you can `apply False_rect` (or `False_rec` if you choose to go with `Set` rather than `Type`), which will leave you to prove `False`. `False` being a `Prop`, you then can use `inversion H1`.

Note that there is a problem in the second branch of your definition of `pred`: you cannot use `(pred nat2 H1)`, as `H1` is not a proof of `pos nat2`. The easiest way is probably to leave an hole here also: `(pred nat2 _)`, which can be trivially solved with an `inversion` (this time, you must build a term of type `pos nat2`, i.e. something that lives in `Prop`).

Comment: Didn't know there was a difference between Set and Type.

Comment: `Type` is in fact a hierarchy of sorts `Type(i)` where `Type(i)` has `Type(i+1)`, with Coq making its best to hide the computations over indices. `Set` can more or less be seen as `Type(0)` (i.e. you explicitely say said you don't want to play with the hierarchy of  `Type`s). See section 4.1.1 for more details